# .NET framework 4.8 deployment in Kubernetes failing using docker file

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, amazon-eks

Below is the docker file that I am using to deploy the application using gitlab and Kubernetes to AWS EKS

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:4.8 AS base

ARG BUILD_ENV

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$BUILD_ENV

WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src
RUN dotnet build "WebSite2..sln" -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebSite2..sln" -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebSite2.dll"]

EXPOSE 80
```

> ERROR: failed to solve: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8: no match for platform in manifest

I tried changing it to 4.7 and 4.6 as well but I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are on Windows with WSL.

If you need to install a Windows Docker image instead of a Linux one, you need to switch to Windows Image Containers first. You can do so using the Docker notification icon. After that, try to install it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).